# Varnish Cache - Connection Refused

Tags: nginx, varnish

I have Nginx running on 8080, while Varnish runs on port 80. I can do

```
wget localhost:8080
```

in shell and get a response, but if I run

```
wget localhost
```

I get connection refused. For reference, I'm trying to access it externally but get the same problem. Hopefully I can solve access from localhost first!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: nitpicking: "bare with me" suggests that you want us to get naked with you. I assume you meant "bear with me" :)

Answer (score 4):

`netstat -tulnp` shows you every port and service running

`iptables -L` shows you if port open or blocked

cheers

Comment: I presume you meant netstat for the first one, thats how I worked out it was running on a non default port (blame an edited sysconfig file, grr). Useful second command, thanks!